# How to securely set up a TLS/SSL Socket connection in Java

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, networking, tls1.2

**TLDR**: I've managed to set up a server and a client that exchange information through sockets with TLS in Java but I'm not entirely sure if the way I did it is good/secure + I'd like to get deeper understanding on how it really works.

I'll walk through the proccess that I followed and I'll ask my questions at the end. I started with a normal client/server set up that exchanged information through sockets locally.

Server:

```
public class Server {
    
    public static final int PORT = 9999;
    public ServerSocket serverSocket;
    
    public Server() {
        try {
            this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            
            startServer();
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    
    public void startServer() {

        System.out.println("[SERVER] Server running on port: " + PORT);
        
        while (!serverSocket.isClosed()) {
            try {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                
                ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler(socket);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    . . .
```

Client:

```
public class Client {
    
    public static final String HOST = "localhost";
    public Socket socket;
    public ObjectOutputStream oos;
    public ObjectInputStream ois;
    public User user;
    
    public Client(User user) {
        try {
            
            this.user = user;
            this.socket = new Socket(HOST, Server.PORT);
            this.oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            this.ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            
            oos.writeObject(user);
            
            listener();
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    
    . . .
```

In order to upgrade the Client and the Server to use TLS I generated a keystore using `keytool` and modified the Server and the Client classes to:

Server:

```
public Server() {
        try {
            
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "keys/server.keystore");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
            
            this.sslServerSocketFactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
             
            this.sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(PORT);
            
            startServer();
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

        . . .
```

Client:

```
public Client(User user) {
        try {
            
            this.user = user;
            
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","keys/client.keystore");
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","password");
            
            this.sslSocketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
             
                        this.sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(HOST, Server.PORT);
            
            this.oos = new ObjectOutputStream(sslSocket.getOutputStream());
            this.ois = new ObjectInputStream(sslSocket.getInputStream());
            
            oos.writeObject(user);
            
            listenForMessage();
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

        . . .
```

How do keystores really work? From my understanding, you generate a keystore with the `keytool` command and that generates a keystore file that is like a small database(?) that contains a self-signed certificate and a public/private key pair. We then create a truststore that's like a keystore but where we only import the self-signed certificate and the public key and this is what the client uses to connect to the server (I don't really understand this very last part).

How do we actually use these keys that we generated inside our code? What is the recommended/secure way to do it? I have a feeling that setting system properties and typing a password in plain text in the class isn't the right way to do it but this might be the way to do it.

If I were to develop an app that uses TLS how would I go about storing the keys in the Client? Would it be possible to pack the key inside the jar file that I'd release for the users to download?

References:
I googled A LOT trying to find answers, found some other stackoverflow posts and tried to understand how it works, and also kind of followed [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html) from the docs.

Like I said, I followed the tutorial from the docs and combining that with some knowledge I got from other stackoverflow posts I managed to make it work but I'd like to understand how everything really works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do keystores really work? From my understanding, you generate a keystore with the `keytool` command and that generates a keystore file that is like a small database(?) that contains a self-signed certificate and a public/private key pair.

Well preferably a certificate chain with a leaf and one or more CA certificates; self signed certificates are usually just a way to "get it working" without a lot of key management. And the certificate contains the public key, so you only need to store the chain + the private key of the server certificate.

> We then create a truststore that's like a keystore but where we only import the self-signed certificate and the public key and this is what the client uses to connect to the server (I don't really understand this very last part).

No, again, the public key doesn't need to store separately, it is already included. And you don't need to have the truststore to connect, you need it to verify the *trust path* to a *trust anchor*. Usually that is a known root certificate, but for self-signed certificates it is just the one certificate.

> How do we actually use these keys that we generated inside our code? What is the recommended/secure way to do it? I have a feeling that setting system properties and typing a password in plain text in the class isn't the right way to do it but this might be the way to do it.

Usually you try and store the private key in the least accessible way possible while you are still able to use it economically. Banks store private keys in HSM's, hardware security modules. Generally, if you just have a computer, you try to store it in the most secure place possible, e.g. in a system provided key store.

Using a key store based on password based encryption (PKCS#12 or PFX keystores and the Java JKS key stores) are indeed not the most secure options. Better choose a *very secure password* to at least not leak the private key if the store gets stolen.

Note that Java does contain a PKCS#11 provider that works with HSM's as well as providers to use the Windows certificates / keys.

> If I were to develop an app that uses TLS how would I go about storing the keys in the Client? Would it be possible to pack the key inside the jar file that I'd release for the users to download?

Yes, it certainly can be a resource that is packed with the program, but you might need to update your program if you want it to remain current. Actually, that is exactly how most browsers get the trust store; the certificates are delivered with the updates of Firefox and Chrome.

For others they are part of OS updates such as with Edge, and you may also have a network specific method of distributing trusted certificates such as the Group Policy in the Windows ecosystem.

> Like I said, I followed the tutorial from the docs and combining that with some knowledge I got from other stackoverflow posts I managed to make it work but I'd like to understand how everything really works.

Well, PKIX and TLS operation is a lot of information to take in and understand for sure. One way of making sure that you get the right information is to simply [read the X.509 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280). There are many tutorials on the Internet as well.

Comment: Thank you very much! Even though my post was all over the place your answer definitely helped me understand this better :)